# Aurelia Webpack 2 Beta Builds Don't Match

Tags: webpack, aurelia, webpack-2

I am currently using Webpack 2 beta with Aurelia. I can't seem to make my builds match each other. I am just learning webpack and can't figure out why the 2 aren't matching since it builds from same config file. For example when I run `npm start` my webpack build ends up looking like so:

[image]

That works really well for us. But when I run `npm run build` my build suddenly changes and looks like so:

[image]

My webpack config:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const AureliaWebpackPlugin = require('aurelia-webpack-plugin');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const project = require('./package.json');
const BrowserSyncPlugin = require('browser-sync-webpack-plugin');

const ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV && process.env.NODE_ENV.toLowerCase() || 'development';
const DEBUG = ENV !== 'production';
const metadata = {
  port: process.env.WEBPACK_PORT || 3000,
  host: process.env.WEBPACK_HOST || 'localhost',
  ENV: ENV,
  HMR: process.argv.join('').indexOf('hot') >= 0 || !!process.env.WEBPACK_HMR
};


module.exports = {
    entry: {
        'app': ['babel-polyfill'], // <-- this array will be filled by the aurelia-webpack-plugin
        'aurelia': Object.keys(project.dependencies).filter(dep => dep.startsWith('aurelia-'))
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve('dist'),
        filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    },
    devServer: {
      port: metadata.port
    },
    devtool: 'source-map',
    resolve: {
      modules: [path.resolve(__dirname, "src"), "node_modules"]
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                query: {
                    presets: ['es2015', 'stage-0'],
                    plugins: ['transform-decorators-legacy']
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                exclude: /index\.html$/, // index.html will be taken care by HtmlWebpackPlugin
                use: [
                    'raw-loader',
                    'html-minifier-loader'
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
            },
            {
              test: [/\.scss$/, /\.sass$/],
              loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                fallbackLoader: 'style-loader',
                loader: 'css-loader?moudules=true&sourceMap!postcss-loader?importLoaders=1!sass-loader?sourceMap',
              }),
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif)$/,
                use: 'url-loader'
            },
            {
              test: /\.json$/,
              use: 'json-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg|woff2?)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
                use: [
                  {
                    loader: 'file-loader',
                    options: {
                      name: '[path][name].[ext]',
                    }
                  }
                ]
            },
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            regeneratorRuntime: 'regenerator-runtime', // to support await/async syntax
            $: 'jquery', // because 'bootstrap' by Twitter depends on this
            jQuery: 'jquery', // just an alias
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: 'index.html',
            favicon: 'favicon.ico'
        }),
        new AureliaWebpackPlugin({
            root: path.resolve(),
            src: path.resolve('src'),
            baseUrl: '/'
        }),
        new ExtractTextPlugin({
          filename: 'global.css',
          allChunks: true,
        }),
        new BrowserSyncPlugin({
          // browse to http://localhost:3000/ during development,
          // ./public directory is being served
          host: 'localhost',
          port: 3001,
          proxy: 'http://localhost:3000/',
        }),
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            name: ['aurelia']
        }),
        new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
          options: {
              debug: DEBUG,
              devtool: 'source-map',
              context: __dirname,
              'html-minifier-loader': {
                  removeComments: true,               // remove all comments
                  collapseWhitespace: true,           // collapse white space between block elements (div, header, footer, p etc...)
                  collapseInlineTagWhitespace: true,  // collapse white space between inline elements (button, span, i, b, a etc...)
                  collapseBooleanAttributes: true,    // <input required="required"/> => <input required />
                  removeAttributeQuotes: true,        // <input class="abcd" /> => <input class=abcd />
                  minifyCSS: true,                    // <input style="display: inline-block; width: 50px;" /> => <input style="display:inline-block;width:50px;"/>
                  minifyJS: true,                     // same with CSS but for javascript
                  removeScriptTypeAttributes: true,   // <script type="text/javascript"> => <script>
                  removeStyleLinkTypeAttributes: true // <link type="text/css" /> => <link />
              },
          }
      }),
    ]
};
```

The NPM scripts look like so:

```
"scripts": {
    "pretest": "del-cli \"test/coverage\"",
    "test": "cross-env BABEL_ENV=node NODE_ENV=test ./node_modules/karma/bin/karma start test/karma.conf.js",
    "test:debug": "npm test -- --single-run=false --debug",
    "webdriver:update": "cross-env ./node_modules/.bin/webdriver-manager update",
    "webdriver:start": "cross-env ./node_modules/.bin/webdriver-manager start",
    "pree2e": "npm run webdriver:update -- --standalone",
    "e2e": "concurrently --success first --kill-others \"npm run e2e:start-when-ready\" \"cross-env WEBPACK_PORT=19876 npm start\"",
    "e2e:start-when-ready": "wait-on --timeout 120000 http-get://localhost:19876/index.html && npm run e2e:start",
    "e2e:start": "cross-env ./node_modules/.bin/protractor test/protractor.conf.js",
    "e2e:live": "npm run e2e:start -- --elementExplorer",
    "clean": "npm cache clean && del-cli node_modules \"test/coverage\" dist",
    "clean:dist": "del-cli dist",
    "preclean:install": "npm run clean",
    "clean:install": "npm install",
    "preclean:start": "npm run clean",
    "clean:start": "npm start",
    "watch": "npm run watch:dev",
    "watch:dev": "npm run build:dev -- --watch",
    "watch:dev:hmr": "npm run watch:dev -- --hot",
    "watch:test": "npm run test -- --auto-watch --no-single-run",
    "watch:prod": "npm run build:prod -- --watch",
    "build": "npm run build:dev",
    "prebuild:dev": "npm run clean:dist",
    "build:dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development npm run webpack -- --progress --profile",
    "prebuild:prod": "npm run clean:dist",
    "build:prod": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production npm run webpack -- --progress --profile",
    "start": "npm run server:dev",
    "server": "npm run server:dev",
    "server:dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node ./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server --inline --profile --watch",
    "server:dev:hmr": "npm run server:dev -- --hot",
    "server:prod": "http-server dist --cors",
    "webpack": "cross-env BABEL_ENV=node ./node_modules/.bin/webpack",
    "webpack-dev-server": "cross-env BABEL_ENV=node ./node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server"
  },
```

Why are they different what is exactly triggering them to be different? I need things like my images to be in.